# Auto-Execute Script upon USB Mount

Tags: python

My main reason for learning Python is to help me with ethical hacking. One of the things that I've wanted to know for a while is how you can auto-start a script upon mount. For example, on Ubuntu, the default setting is to automatically mount a USB. My fear is that there must be a way to execute a script upon mount, so I've always turned off that feature. But I would certainly like to know how it's done, ideally with you showing me an example using code.

Answer (score 0):

Not to get into detail, it's up to operating system settings, on linux you would do something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted) , but note to hack that , you'd have to somehow hack into shell first, to execute these commands for your specific usb, and on windows you have to setup autoplay setting to start program, and then  autorun.inf on usb for exe files which is shown how to do [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/autolaunch-apps-usb-stick-windows/) , and anyway you'd have to hack directly os to do it, so if you hack os, you don't need to transfer scripts from usb, you could run them directly :)

So ending there :) It's not as easy as you might think ;)